# Can PDF user password be used to remove encryption?

Tags: parsing, pdf, encryption, passwords

It seems that Portable Document Format (PDF) tools, even open-source software, require that the master password of an encrypted document be supplied to convert the PDF file to an unencrypted version.  I am in a situation in which I have the user password but not the master password.  Is there any particular reason (algorithmic or encryption-related) that the master password is technically required to convert the file and that the user password is not enough, or is this difference merely a policy enforced by the application itself?  Common sense tells me that if the user password is enough for a program to parse and display the PDF file, then that should technically be enough to save the decrypted contents to a converted file as well.  This makes me wonder if the third-party software enforces the master/user password difference just for the sake of principle or perhaps out of fear of lawsuits from Adobe...

Are there any applications that can convert a PDF file with only knowing the user password and not the master password?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: *Common sense tells me that if the user password is enough for a program to parse and display the PDF file, then that should technically be enough to save the decrypted contents to a converted file as well.* - common sense is correct here.

Comment: You are correct, there are plenty PDF decryption utilities out there, although they are mostly payware. If you can read it you can decrypt it, unless the entire chain from server to display is protected (and then you can make a photograph).

Comment: The user password gives you the right to open and view the file. It does not give you the right to modify the document; for modifying the document you would need the master password (if it has been set). With the master password, there are a set of rights you do nevertheless have. The master password gives you access to these rights.

Answer (score 1):

ok. Here is the easy solution.

1. Open the PDF with Google chrome.
2. Enter the password.
3. Print document using Ctrl+p.
4. Choose Save as PDF option.

Done.

Since it's a copy of original PDF without any securities, you can try anything with the new PDF.

Comment: Solutions using some *print* command usually have the deficiency that they either flatten or disregard annotations. Depending on the PDF in question that may cripple it substantially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's technically possible - indeed, easy.

Years ago, there was some language in the old PDF reference manual implying that, since the syntax of PDF operators was copyright Adobe, it would be illegal to ship software which allowed decryption against Adobe's wishes. Not being a lawyer, I don't know if that actually had any force.

I can't find any similar language in the new ISO 32000 standard, so I don't know what Adobe rely on now, other than goodwill.